# Angular 6: Refresh a component after an action

Tags: angular

I have two components, one that displays a list of products and another component that allows products to be updated. They both share the same products service and I'm having trouble refreshing the list of products components list after the product has been updated. I have figured out a way to use a Subject but it feels hacky.

product-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService} from '@app/products/product.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-product-list' 
   templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'
   styleUrls: './product-list.component.css'
})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void{
   this.products = [];
   this.productService.Approved$.subscribe(() => this.refreshComponent())
  }

 getProducts(): void {
   this.productservice.getProducts().subscribe(products => {this.products = products})
 }

 refreshComponent(): void {
  this.getProducts()
 }
}
```

product-submit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService} from '@app/products/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-submit'
  templateUrl: './product-submit.component.html'
  styleUrls: ['./product-submit.component.css']
})

export class ProductSubmitComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

onSubmit(text:string) {
  this.productService.updateProduct(productIds, text).subscribe(
   () => {this.productService.submittedapprov.next();
  });
 }
}
```

product.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, Output} from '@angular/core'
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http'
import {Observable, throwError, Subject} from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ProductService {
  submittedapprov = new Subject();
  submittedApproval$ = this.submittedapprov.asObservable();

 constructor(private http: HttpClient){
 ...
 }

 updateProduct(productIds: number[], text: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.apiurl)
 }

 getProducts(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiurl)
 }
}
```

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/prabhatmishra33/ShoppingSiteMeanJSApp/blob/master/src/app/shopping-list/shoppinglist.service.ts I have used observable in this project to subscribe to the change event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options here.

- If you want to refresh by regetting all of the data from the server, you can simply call your `getProducts()` method, which is looks like you are doing now.
- You can retain the list of products in the service instead and when products are added/removed, add/remove them from the list in the service. Then if you bind to that list in any component that needs the list, it will be updated automatically using Angular's data binding. I have a demo of this in the below mentioned stackblitz.

I have an example in a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no-subject-deborahk

It demonstrates the very simple option of using a getter. It then provides the same functionality again using a `BehaviorSubject` so you can evaluate the two techniques and decide which works best for your particular scenario.